# Tkinter messagebox fails when the root window is closed

Tags: python, tkinter

Tkinter messagebox generates an exception when I close the parent window ignoring the message box.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox 
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("100x100")
w = tk.Label(root, text="I am root")
w.pack()
messagebox.showerror("Message Box", "Error")
root.mainloop()
```

This is a pain because I want to do processing after the root window has closed. I cannot see any way of making messagebox windows modal. I can set up my own dialogs, but I would rather use standard ready made code if I can.

Comment: How do you replicate that Exception? I can close either the window or the message box with no errors.

Comment: Open the above code in Thonny. Hit the run button. Ignore the message box in front. Hit the close button of the greyed out window behind it. The error is: _tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "grab" command: application has been destroyed. I get the same result in a terminal and with Idle. I am hoping that it is a known bug. better still a fixed known bug. Google does not seem to help. I am using Python 3.8.5 and Xubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 2):

By default, the messagebox gets attached to the first running window, you can over-ride this and specify another window, so as a workaround you can set the 'Master' of the messagebox to be a hidden window, which the user can't close.  i.e.:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox 
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("100x100")
w = tk.Label(root, text="I am root 1")
w.pack()

root2 = tk.Tk()
root2.withdraw()

messagebox.showerror("Message Box", "Error", master=root2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes, that is a good try. It works for the simple example. It hits problems with messagebox.askyesno. Our unhelpful user closes root while the message box is visible. He then dismisses the message box which returns a False value. I hit problems processing that because the main window has gone. I could trap the main window close event and set a flag, but that is messy. More simply, I could not bother with root2 and just trap the exception. I could then call the close down code and sys.exit. Again, it is messy if I have to do that for every message box.

Answer (score 1):

My suggested solution was trapping the message box exception that is generated when the main is closed before dismissing the message box. That worked for message boxes, but it did not work for simple dialogs. The best solution appears to be to disable the close button on the main window before opening the dialog and to re-enabling it afterwards. Here is a simple example to illustrate the procedure:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog
close_enabled = False # Main window close button enabled.

def On_Closing():
    # User has clicked the main window close button.
    if close_enabled == False: return
    print('Close down processing')
    root.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", On_Closing)
root.geometry("100x100")
w = tk.Label(root, text="I am root")
w.pack()
close_enabled = False # Disable main window close button.
answer = simpledialog.askstring('Title', 'Type Your Name')
close_enabled = True # Enable main window close button.
print(answer)
root.mainloop()
```

The only disadvantage is that the dialog disappears behind the main window when the (deactivated) main window close button is clicked. Message boxes do stay on top, which is more helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

For your case, you need to call `root.wait_visibility()` before showing the message box:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox 
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("100x100")
w = tk.Label(root, text="I am root")
w.pack()
root.wait_visibility()
messagebox.showerror("Message Box", "Error")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: No that does not work with Python 3.8.5 and Xubuntu 20.04. I still get: _tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "grab" command: application has been destroyed

Comment: Then try calling `root.withdraw()` before showing the message box and calling `root.deiconify()` after.

Comment: That works, but it is not attractive for the user to see the main window disappear. If I code the dialog myself, I can use root.wait_window(child), but I do not have a handle for child if I use a message box. As I have said, I can use try: ..... except: shut_down(). Nonetheless, JeffUK said messagebox worked properly on his machine. I like that solution better.